# How can I boot Linux and Windows with grub?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

After installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, booting from hard disk option leads to loading of grub. All I see is the following:

```
grub>
```

I don't know what to do, even with the "help" option. I don't understand how to manage with commands of grub.

How can I boot Linux and Windows with grub?

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the `grub>` prompt:

```
grub> insmod normal
grub> normal
```

You should then be presented with the normal GRUB screen, from which you can choose Ubuntu, Windows or whatever else.

To fix this permanently after booting into Ubuntu:

1. Run this command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Find the line that says:

   ```
   GRUB_TERMINAL=console
   ```

   and place a `#` symbol in front of it, so that it looks like this:

   ```
   #GRUB_TERMINAL=console
   ```
3. Save and close the file.
4. Run this command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```